# select case with date format VBA

Tags: excel, vba

i have a little problem in using select case with date formatted text box

```
dim youm as date 
Select Case youm
Case ""
MsgBox "write date "
Exit Sub
End Select
```

Comment: You're dealing with text (`String`) then, not a `Date`?

Comment: As stated above, you try dealing with text. Excel keeps dates as numeric. So, using `Case 0` you'll make the code running. But it would be a bad way of codding. It is enough to use `Option Explicit` on top of the respective module and it will warn you that `youm` has been declared but it did not receive any value...